# Trying to plot outliers using DBSCAN

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, dbscan

I have never been great with Python plotting concepts, and now I'm still apparently missing something new.

Here is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
from numpy import genfromtxt
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

data = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\path_here\\wine.csv')
data

# Reading in 2D Feature Space
model = DBSCAN(eps=0.9, min_samples=10).fit(data)


array_flavanoids = data.iloc[:, 2]

# Slicing array
array_colorintensity = data.iloc[:, 3]

# Scatter plot function
colors = model.labels_
plt.scatter(array_flavanoids, array_colorintensity, c=colors, marker='o')
plt.xlabel('Concentration of flavanoids', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('Color intensity', fontsize=16)
plt.title('Concentration of flavanoids vs Color intensity', fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

Here is my result.

[image]

I am expecting the outliers to be in a different color than the non-outliers.  So, something like this.

[image]

Maybe one color for outliers and another for non-outliers.  I am just trying to learn the concept in this exercise.  I am trying to follow the example from this link.

https://towardsdatascience.com/outlier-detection-python-cd22e6a12098

I am using this data source.

https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/red-wine-quality-cortez-et-al-2009

Comment: noise points (=outliers, i.e. data points that couldn't be assigned to any cluster) are labeled with `-1`. Obviously your DBSCAN parameters create a model that assigns all data points to the same set. Your example is not reproducable as the plotted data are not from the indicated dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am testing different data sets.
I got this to work.

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

def dbscan(X, eps, min_samples):
    ss = StandardScaler()
    X = ss.fit_transform(X)
    db = DBSCAN(eps=eps, min_samples=min_samples)
    db.fit(X)
    y_pred = db.fit_predict(X)
    plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1],c=y_pred, cmap='Paired')
    plt.title("DBSCAN")
        
dbscan(data, eps=.5, min_samples=5)
```

[image]

I found this to be a great resource.

https://medium.com/@plog397/functions-to-plot-kmeans-hierarchical-and-dbscan-clustering-c4146ed69744